# Lisp function for duplicate elements

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am beginner in LISP so I need to write a function `(DUPLICATE-ELEMENTS L)`, which checks the repeated occurrence of an element (atom or list) in L.

Example:

```
(DUPLICATE-ELEMENTS '(a b a c)) -> T
(DUPLICATE-ELEMENTS '(a b (a b)) -> NIL
(DUPLICATE-ELEMENTS '(a b (a b) c d (a b))) -> T
```

I have found this function that checks for unique

```
(defun Unique (l)
  (or (null l)
      (and (not (member (car l) (cdr l)))
           (Unique (cdr l)))))
```

But I need viceversa like in example. Could you please help me.
When i run this 
`(Unique '(a b a c))` I receive `NIL`, but i need to receive `T`

Comment: That's great! Learning Lisp is a lot of fun. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: I have updated question...

Comment: Why not change the function UNIQUE? The function to invert a truth value is called NOT.

Comment: Most Lisps are case-insensitive, so your choice of name `Unique` looks strange. In modern style most code is written in lowercase, even though it *appears* un uppercase when printed out.

Comment: How could I make this function to work with lists? When I put this `(DUPLICATE-ELEMENTS ‘(a b (a b))` I get `NIL` result, but when I put this `(DUPLICATE-ELEMENTS ‘(a b (a b) c d (a b)))` I get also `NIL`, but the correct result should be `T`

Comment: `member` only uses `#'eql` as `:test` when not provided. That means it does not match structures that look the same but only primitive values and numbers. If you add `:test #'equal` as keywords to the `member` fucntion then it maches: `(member '(a b) '(c d (a b)) :test #'equal) ; ==> ((a b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
(defun unique (data-list)
  (or (null data-list)
      (and (not (member (car data-list) (cdr data-list) :test #'equalp))
           (unique (cdr data-list)))))

(defun duplicate-elements (data-list)
  (not (unique data-list)))
```

? Also you can declare predicate for comparing as parameter your function. Why do you think your `DUPLICATE-ELEMENTS` return `nil` when you waiting for `T`? I think that's take place because `member` used for comparing values some default predicate. Perhaps it's an `eq`, which did not use for list compare. Seee this exaple:

```
(defun unique (data-list &key (test #'eq))
  (or (null data-list)
      (and (not (member (car data-list) (cdr data-list) :test test))
           (unique (cdr data-list)))))

(defun duplicate-elements (data-list &key (test #'eq))
  (not (unique data-list :test test)))
```

and how to use them to take the right result:

```
CL-USER> (duplicate-elements '((a b) a c (a b)))
NIL
CL-USER> (duplicate-elements '((a b) a c (a b)) :test #'equalp)
T
```